# How to place a editable text box in grid using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I am currently working on grids in dojo and my requirement is to have a editable text box in the data grid. I have tried using editable:true in the layout, but the text box appears only after i double click the field. I want that text box while the grid is populated and the user has to click the field only once. Is there any way to do it?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dojox/grid/_Grid` instances support a `singleClickEdit` property.  It is `false` by default, which requires double-clicking to edit.  Set it to `true` to require only single-click instead.